# Carry Desktop From Computer To Computer

Tags: windows-7, desktop

Is it possible to have your desktop (shortcuts, folders, etc) be the exact same regardless of which computer you log onto?

I am constantly having to log on to diff computers in our domain to make tweaks/change settings and the files/folders that are quickly accessible from my "home" desktop aren't as easy to locate.  Is it possible, to have the desktop be the same for ANY computer on the domain I log onto?

Comment: Sure here's one way.... [Deploy Roaming User Profiles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649079.aspx) for the DOMAIN computers on that domain.

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE - probably not, but is their an option that does not involve GPO?

Comment: If you're not mapping drives, printers, configuring Outlook and a bunch of other things, then just for shortcuts, and files and folders, why not just have a home drive that maps on all PCs when you sign onto them in your domain (either the AD Home Folder or a mapped drive login script) and then just go to it from all domain PCs you're signed onto for getting that stuff?

Comment: ALong with @LMFAO_A_JOKE, the only way to do this would be to use Profile Path under the Profile tab on your active directory object, which is what the article posted above tells you to do.  I have a few users that use this feature as they travel around our organization and it works pretty good.

I also agree that a home folder might be the better option, especially if you do not need your complete profile on every machine.